# Exporting a TypeScript module results in interfaces not getting picked up

Tags: signalr, typescript

I'm using TypeScript and SignalR together, and am trying to define static types for the generated SignalR classes. And if I do something like this, it works:

```
///<reference path="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.d.ts" />
///<reference path="../Scripts/signalr-1.0.d.ts" />

interface SignalR {
    roomHub: Service.RoomHub;
}

module Service {
        export var roomHub = $.connection.roomHub;
        export interface RoomHub { }
}
```

And of course `$.connection` is of type `SignalR`, which is defined in the file "signalr-1.0.d.ts", and extended in the file above.

However, I need to be able to reference the `Service` module from other files, so I need to add the "export" keywords to both the module and the interface, i.e.:

```
///<reference path="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.d.ts" />
///<reference path="../Scripts/signalr-1.0.d.ts" />

export interface SignalR {
    roomHub: Service.RoomHub;
}

export module Service {
    // Error here: "The property 'roomHub' does not exist on type SignalR."
    export var roomHub = $.connection.roomHub;
    export interface RoomHub { }
}
```

However, when I do that, I get a little red squiggly line under `$.connection.roomHub`, and the compiler returns the error, "The property 'roomHub' does not exist on type SignalR."

I certainly don't understand everything about TypeScript, but that doesn't seem right to me. Have I run into a compiler bug? Or is there a different way to do this?

Comment: Slight tangent, but i thought you might be interested, I wrote a T4 template to generate the .d.ts from your hubs: https://gist.github.com/4583549

Comment: @RobFonseca-Ensor - Further evidence that no good deed goes unpunished: I just posted on that Gist the problems I was having with it :-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to figure out a workaround. I pulled out the interfaces into a separate file:

```
// File: ISignalR.ts
interface SignalR {
    roomHub: RoomHub;
}

interface RoomHub {
}
```

And then I referenced that file in my Service file

```
///<reference path="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.d.ts" />
///<reference path="../Scripts/signalr-1.0.d.ts" />
///<reference path="ISignalR.ts" />

export module Service {
    export var roomHub = $.connection.roomHub;
}
```

And that works, oddly enough. I'm not sure if it's a compiler bug, or something I'm continuing to misunderstand, but it clearly has something to do with some subtle semantic changes related to the AMD module support. I'd love to hear more of an explanation from someone who groks TypeScript and/or RequireJS modules a little better than I do.

Answer (score 2):

If the `SignalR` object has actual members, you want to use the `declare module` syntax instead. `interface` declarations only describe members on types (rather than describing extant objects).

```
///<reference path="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.d.ts" />
///<reference path="../Scripts/signalr-1.0.d.ts" />

declare module SignalR {
    var roomHub: Service.RoomHub;
}

export module Service {
    // Good now
    export var roomHub = $.connection.roomHub;
    export interface RoomHub { }
}
```

Comment: With that exact code, I get the same error: a little red squiggly on `$.connection.roomHub`, and the message, "The property 'roomHub' does not exist on type SignalR." And I *think* (I'm not sure) that the `interface` syntax is appropriate, since it's describing the interface that the `$.connection` object is presenting to the world.

Comment: How is $.connection being declared?

Comment: It gets defined at runtime in the file `jquery.signalR-1.0.0-alpha2.js`, and at compile-time in the definitions file `signalr-1.0.d.ts` (https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/signalr/signalr-1.0.d.ts).

Answer (score 2):

There is more than one way to wire SignalR up, and using `createHubProxy` and `invoke` are more TypeScript friendly:

```
export class FrameworkHub {

    private connection: HubConnection;
    private proxy: HubProxy;

    Init(): void {
        this.Connected = false;
        this.connection = $.hubConnection();
        this.connection.logging = true;
        // Binding with createHubProxy means you can use a string name, so no need to add dynamic properties to the hub
        this.proxy = this.connection.createHubProxy("MyHubName"); 
        this.wireEventListeners();
        this.initializeConnection();
    }

    // Binding with proxy.on means you can use a string name for the function, so no need to add dynamic properties to the hub.
    wireEventListeners(): void {
        this.proxy.on("HandleFrameworkMessage", (message: IFrameworkMessage) => {
            console.log("HandleFrameworkMessage: " + message.AccountID + " - " + message.ArmID);
            // Do something to handle the message here.
        });
    }

    initializeConnection(): void {
        //console.log("Framework Hub initializeConnection");
        var that = this;
        //Again, using invoke means passing a string argument.
        this.connection.start().done(() => {
            that.proxy.invoke("Connect", this.AccountID, this.ArmID).done((response:FrameworkHubResponse) => {
                //console.log("FHR: " + response.Success + " - " + response.Message);
                if (response.Success) {
                    // Do something.
                }
                else {
                    // Try again. Would be better with some kind of exponential back-off.
                    setTimeout(that.initializeConnection, 500);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

That's a slightly rough example cut from real code, but I've found it the best TS way to use SignalR. Docs for this kind of connection are here: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client-Hubs-%28No-Proxy%29 - watch out because the Docs haven't always kept pace with the recent changes.

Comment: I'm still wrapping my head around SignalR - so what would you say are the advantages to using this approach rather than the automatically generated proxies? If I use the automatically generated proxies with TS, yeah, I need to define their interfaces manually - but I guess I kind of like the separation of concerns, so that I don't have any magic strings hanging about in the code that I control. Of course, ideally, it would be awesome to have SignalR generate the TS interfaces right alongside the JS code.

Comment: It's a matter of style, really. I'm still getting used to SignalR as well, but working this way feels more like working with any other PubSub component (Most event handling in JS is pretty much built around magic strings, so it feels normal to me). Dynamic objects feel a bit anti-TS (which is a paradox, because JS is of course built around them), and I'm going to turn the above class into a generic HubManager, which I can pass the hub name into and then just wire up with event listeners.

Comment: Of course one way to deal with the magic strings is to create an enum (not a TS one, for the moment, as they are still experimental - but just a class with static string members). This is what I've done with the Azure ServiceBus, another string-based PubSub system, and it works pretty well.